# How can I extend my template with thymeleaf?

Tags: html, templates, layout, thymeleaf

I'd like to get a view that displays these two files in one page. I've followed syntax but yet I'm unabled to get a proper view.

Layout page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <p>Changing contents</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="skeleton.html"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

  <body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">

      <!--Content of the page-->
      <h3>page injected in another page</h3>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is just the content of the content page with this text:
**page injected in another page**

Could anyone say me what's wrong with my code please?

Answer (score 1):

For `layout:decorate` you need to use [Standard Expression Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax), something like ... `layout:decorate="~{skeleton}"` will work, depend on the location of your `skeleton.html` file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've already tried this (layout:decorate="~{skeleton}") but it doesn't work, whereas my skeleton file is directly in templates directory (no in subdirectory). And I still get "page injected in another page" text, and that's all. Layout page doesn't display. What else can I try ?

Comment: Did you configure layout dialect, according to [manual](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#configuration)? Also, add the file names above each HTML snippet in your description. I'd like to know for sure where is your `skeleton.html`. Provide the URL you are using to display the resulting page.

Comment: I have no idea where I should copy/paste code of "template engine". I see no file with this name. Where should I add this code?

Comment: Inside your Thymeleaf configuration. Does this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines) work for you? Read it through and do the same.

Comment: I have just a class named ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class, am I supposed to add the code inside this class? Because I see "ThymeleafConfiguration" on baeldung website.